# Pandas (>1.3.x) read_csv UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' but it worked ok with Pandas (<=1.2.5)

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

So far I was working with Pandas 1.2.2, after to upgrade it to 1.3.1 I have the next error when I read a csv file, I didn't have any problem before upgrade.

Here is de kind of encoding for the file:

```
>>> with open('file.csv') as f:
...     print(f)
... 
<_io.TextIOWrapper name='file.csv' mode='r' encoding='UTF-8'>
```

With Pandas (<=1.2.5) the file was reading ok, this is an example of this:

```
Python 3.9.2 (default, Feb 19 2021, 17:23:45) 
[GCC 8.3.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> pd.show_versions()

INSTALLED VERSIONS
------------------
commit           : 7c48ff4409c622c582c56a5702373f726de08e96
python           : 3.9.2.final.0
python-bits      : 64
OS               : Linux
OS-release       : 5.10.25-linuxkit
Version          : #1 SMP Tue Mar 23 09:27:39 UTC 2021
machine          : x86_64
processor        : 
byteorder        : little
LC_ALL           : None
LANG             : C.UTF-8
LOCALE           : en_US.UTF-8

pandas           : 1.2.5
numpy            : 1.21.1
pytz             : 2021.1
dateutil         : 2.8.2
pip              : 21.2.1
setuptools       : 53.0.0
Cython           : None
pytest           : None
hypothesis       : None
sphinx           : None
blosc            : None
feather          : None
xlsxwriter       : 1.4.4
lxml.etree       : None
html5lib         : None
pymysql          : None
psycopg2         : None
jinja2           : 3.0.1
IPython          : 7.25.0
pandas_datareader: None
bs4              : None
bottleneck       : None
fsspec           : None
fastparquet      : None
gcsfs            : None
matplotlib       : 3.4.2
numexpr          : None
odfpy            : None
openpyxl         : 3.0.7
pandas_gbq       : None
pyarrow          : None
pyxlsb           : 1.0.8
s3fs             : None
scipy            : 1.7.0
sqlalchemy       : None
tables           : None
tabulate         : None
xarray           : None
xlrd             : None
xlwt             : None
numba            : None
>>> gmast = pd.read_csv('file.csv', decimal= ",", sep=';')

>>> gmast.shape
(191502, 6)
```

With Pandas(>= 1.3.x)

```
Python 3.9.2 (default, Feb 19 2021, 17:23:45) 
[GCC 8.3.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> pd.show_versions()

INSTALLED VERSIONS
------------------
commit           : c7f7443c1bad8262358114d5e88cd9c8a308e8aa
python           : 3.9.2.final.0
python-bits      : 64
OS               : Linux
OS-release       : 5.10.25-linuxkit
Version          : #1 SMP Tue Mar 23 09:27:39 UTC 2021
machine          : x86_64
processor        : 
byteorder        : little
LC_ALL           : None
LANG             : C.UTF-8
LOCALE           : en_US.UTF-8

pandas           : 1.3.1
numpy            : 1.21.1
pytz             : 2021.1
dateutil         : 2.8.2
pip              : 21.2.1
setuptools       : 53.0.0
Cython           : None
pytest           : None
hypothesis       : None
sphinx           : None
blosc            : None
feather          : None
xlsxwriter       : 1.4.4
lxml.etree       : None
html5lib         : None
pymysql          : None
psycopg2         : None
jinja2           : 3.0.1
IPython          : 7.25.0
pandas_datareader: None
bs4              : None
bottleneck       : None
fsspec           : None
fastparquet      : None
gcsfs            : None
matplotlib       : 3.4.2
numexpr          : None
odfpy            : None
openpyxl         : 3.0.7
pandas_gbq       : None
pyarrow          : None
pyxlsb           : 1.0.8
s3fs             : None
scipy            : 1.7.0
sqlalchemy       : None
tables           : None
tabulate         : None
xarray           : None
xlrd             : None
xlwt             : None
numba            : None

>>> gmast = pd.read_csv('file.csv', decimal= ",", sep=';')

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/aaa/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/util/_decorators.py", line 311, in wrapper
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/aaa/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/io/parsers/readers.py", line 586, in read_csv
    return _read(filepath_or_buffer, kwds)
  File "/home/aaa/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/io/parsers/readers.py", line 488, in _read
    return parser.read(nrows)
  File "/home/aaa/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/io/parsers/readers.py", line 1047, in read
    index, columns, col_dict = self._engine.read(nrows)
  File "/home/aaa/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/io/parsers/c_parser_wrapper.py", line 223, in read
    chunks = self._reader.read_low_memory(nrows)
  File "pandas/_libs/parsers.pyx", line 801, in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader.read_low_memory
  File "pandas/_libs/parsers.pyx", line 857, in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader._read_rows
  File "pandas/_libs/parsers.pyx", line 843, in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader._tokenize_rows
  File "pandas/_libs/parsers.pyx", line 1917, in pandas._libs.parsers.raise_parser_error
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x96 in position 205520: invalid start byte
```

If I use the encoding cp1252 it works.

```
gmast = pd.read_csv('file.csv', decimal= ",", sep=';', encoding='cp1252')

>>> gmast.shape
(191502, 6)
```

I don't understand it.
Do anyone have the a similar issue?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the exeption and pandas version, the problem could be that you have non-Unicode character(s) in your file, that was suppressed before v1.3. See [this](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/39450#issuecomment-769960851) bug report comment.

Also, pandas [documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html) introduced the `encoding_errors` parameter (*encoding_errors str, optional, default “strict”*) in **version 1.3** to explicitly handle encoding errors. So you should check your file for incorrect characters.

In any case, if you want the behavior prior v1.3, you can use `replace` (or `ignore` if it better for your case):

```py
gmast = pd.read_csv('file.csv', decimal= ",", sep=';', encoding_errors='replace')
```